# Remove keyboard focus from a form element after it goes out of viewport

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, viewport, blur, intersection-observer

How can I use the relatively new [`Intersection Observer API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to detect when `input` that’s currently focused goes outside the `viewport`, so that when it does, the focus on that `input` is removed?

The solution should work in Safari for iOS.

---

Here is my code so far:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _ => {
  const focusedInput = document.activeElement
  
  // ?
  focusedInput.blur()
})
```

```css
html { height: 100% }

html, body, main, section {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1
}

main { flex-direction: column }

section {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 100%
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <form action=submit method=post>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter Your Details</legend>
        <label>Email<br><input type=email name=email placeholder=jane@example.com></label><hr>
        <label>Message<br><textarea name=briefing placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."></textarea></label><hr>
        <input type=submit value=Submit>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Second Page</h2>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In doc you linked there is a fiddle 
Why don't you use it?

Just modify it to something like..

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _ => {
    let observerOptions = {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: "0px",
        threshold: [0, 0.1, 0.99]
    };

    let intersectionCallback = (entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.intersectionRatio == 0) { // fully invisible
          //document.activeElement.blur()
        }
        if (entry.intersectionRatio < 1) { // partially invisible
          document.activeElement.blur()
        }
      });
    }
    
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionCallback, observerOptions);
    observer.observe(document.querySelector("#myForm"));
  
})
```

```css
html { height: 100% }

html, body, main, section {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1
}

main { flex-direction: column }

section {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 100%
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <form action=submit method=post id=myForm>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter Your Details</legend>
        <label>Email<br><input type=email name=email placeholder=jane@example.com></label><hr>
        <label>Message<br><textarea name=briefing placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."></textarea></label><hr>
        <input type=submit value=Submit>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Second Page</h2>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Checked on browserstack iOS13 Safari - it works. In fiddle it is implement only to form. you can easly extend it to specific fields.

Answer (score 1):

I created a jsfiddle with the behavior you are describing:

```
var intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
  if (entries[0].intersectionRatio <= 0){
    console.log("the field is not visible");
    //Add your blur code here
  }else{
    console.log("the field is visible")
  }
});

// start observing
intersectionObserver.observe(document.querySelector('#emailtwo'));
```

The observer checks the intersectionRatio, if the ratio <= 0 it means the element is not on the screen.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0f9Lkbgc/1/